# FullCalendar date on drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm working on my final project on my school and I'm using FullCalendar, external dragging version.

The thing is that I'm trying to use a button to save the events I drop on the calendar on a Database. To do that I actually need the date the event has been drop. I've read already on FullCalendar documentation and this is the nearest I've reach:

```
drop: function(date) {
        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
            // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
            $(this).remove();
        }
        //date on secs since epoch
        console.log("Dropped on: "+date);
    },
```

This works for the first time I drop an event, but not if I change the event day once I drop for the first time.

Thanks for your help and excuse me for my English, not native.

EDIT: To be clearer: I need the date an event is dropped on. I couldn't find anything to get it. When I drop an event then a 'span' is created on a table inside the calendar, but no date anywhere but the 'thead' of the table, which is separated from the 'tbody' where the events are.

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? The event doesn't fire? The date is wrong or not populated? Please give a bit more detail.

Comment: More details given on Edit. :)

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't really clarify things - I'm unsure why the HTML structure of the calendar is relevant to this. You originally said _"This works for the first time I drop an event, but not if I change the event day once I drop for the first time."_ So, the second time you drop the event, what doesn't work? Why can't you get the date from the `date` parameter in the "drop" callback? Is the callback fired? Is the date value empty or incorrect?